# Double click on dock icon to open a window in the current space

Tags: mojave, dock, spaces

Say I have multiple spaces/desktop open. Desktop 2 is my current one with no [someapp] windows, Desktop 1 has a [someapp] window open.

If I click on the [someapp] icon in the doc the system first puts the title bar up top. If I click again I am brought to Desktop one where [someapp] is (a random one if multiples are open, to boot).

I would like instead for the second click to open a new window in the current space.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Note that I would like this to be default behavior for ALL apps on dock. I know I can use an apple script to bind "Open new window here" to an icon.

The obvious alternatives (right click to open a new window after noticing the first click didn't open one or use a cmd + N or similar) are too cumbersome.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: *I know I can use an apple script to bind "Open new window here" to an icon*... Uhh... can you provide a link for that? I don't quite see how that's possible.

Comment: All the "related questions" solutions were in that vein